# Blender preview showing all white

Tags: materials

[image]

Hello after one crash when rendering small animation, returned to blender and in preview is everything white, render looks ok, but i want to see my materials.

Anyone know reason?

Comment: Either this is a glitch, or you have too many dim lights in the scene, that is it.

Comment: I have just one sun light, how can i solve this problem? Is there any way?

Comment: It could be a problem with the textures. Did you pack them into the .blend?